# Using a keyfile in robomongo

Tags: mongodb, security, authentication, robo3t

I have a MongoDB using a [keyFile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/#enforce-keyfile-access-control-on-existing-replica-set).

I **can't** see from the robomongo docs how to connect to the databased using this type of authentication.

Would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Comment: keyfile is used in a mongo cluster for authentication among replica set, Are you trying to use a keyfile to replace the regular username/password authentication? I doubt you can do that if that's the case.

Comment: Hi @RicoChen I think you right! I want getting an Error that it could not list the DBs, but this could be because the cluster was still not setup yet 